PowerShell - Extract file version and date modified from from file in Zip file
I am trying to get the file version from binaries and the date modified from the SQL file and encountered issues
This is my ZIP
$vipFile = Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction Stop -Path "C:\Patch_2029274.vip"

This is the file name I want to find:
$file = 'Pulling%20AD_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql'

This is the function that should be fixed (the function should return file version in case of binary (EXE, DLL) and date modified for SQL file)
function ReadFileContentFromArchive {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ZipFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$TargetFile
    )

    #workaround because this fails: [Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression') 
    #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"

    $zipReader = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile)

    $zipEntry = $zipReader.GetEntry($targetFile)

}

This is how it should run:
$FileInfo = ReadFileContentFromArchive -ZipFile $vipFile -TargetFile $file

Except for the fact I need to improve the function I am even unable to get the right file because the object holds the full path as below:
This is the content of $zipReader
Entries                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Mode
-------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ----
{IDUDatabase_4.0.0.131/IDUDatabase/AD_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_DerivedRelations-sp.sql, IDUDatabase_4.0.0.131/IDUDatabase/Pulling%20AD_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql, IDUDatabase_4.0.0.131/filesSources.txt, vip.manifest...} Read


The function ReadFileContentFromArchive closes a $streamreader that is not a parameter. Is $streamreader a global variable? It also returns a variable $fileContent that is not assigned locally. If that is a global variable, why do you return it?  It looks like you should review the code you posted in the question, before helpful comments or answers are possible.

The function is not completed and therefore I am asking that question

I don't think you can't get the file version without writing the executable files to disk... would that be a problem for you use case?

Yes it will be a problem

You need to enumerate through the Entries and properties foreach($Entry in $zipReader.Entries) { ......}  Then do same with properties of each $Entry

Hi @jdwend can you help with the solution? what about the file version ispossible?

As Mathias said, doesn't seem to be possible at least with .NET, to get the FileVersion info from a stream, ergo you need to extract the file. Even the native function takes a path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa.

You can get the file content and the last modified date from a zip entry however, it's not possible to get the FileVersionInfo from a stream, even using the native function, i.e.: GetFileVersionInfoA function (winver.h) requires a path as first argument, meaning you will need to extract the zip entry to a temporary path and then delete it.
The PSCompression Module can simplify this process in case you're moving forward, the code could be something like this if you want to target all .sql files in a Zip:
Get-ZipEntry C:\Patch_2029274.vip -Include *.sql -PipelineVariable entry |
    Expand-ZipEntry -Destination $env:TEMP -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object {
        $versionInfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName)
        $_.Delete()

        [pscustomobject]@{
            LastWriteTime = $entry.LastWriteTime
            Name          = $entry.Name
            Path          = $entry.RelativePath
            VersionInfo   = $versionInfo.FileVersion
        }
    }

If you simply need to get the zip entry content you can use Get-ZipEntryContent from the same module (this doesn't require extracting the entry).
